# In-house designer yearly goals - How to be descriptive

Tags: work

Our organization has to complete yearly goals and I don't know how to elaborate and this is my problem for years. I have the goals but can't fully explain in detail. I am surrounded by editors that have a full page of detail and I can't even get half of page. My current goals are; Customize infographics, create a media kit for our publications, develop a project tracking system and attend professional development classes.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd argue this should be asked over on workplace.se Employee goals are mostly HR political BS and aren't really germane to any particular career track.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ideas.

If you use a **tracking system** for your work, you can use your completed tasks as inspiration for your next goal items. They are usually descriptive enough, and hold real value.

If you don't, the same applies. It's always useful to think of **a goal as  set of tasks**. What steps will you take when preparing, for example, the infographics? You will need to do some research for the field (what type of research, where, for how long, what will you be focusing on while doing it, etc). You will also do mockups, and for them you will need assets. Where do you intend to get them? Do you need anything else to locate them? Then, will you be editing your assets? Do you need custom fonts? How will you get it revised? What about distribution?

Try to imagine your goal as a plan, and the descriptions as real steps you would (or will) take. Don't add noise for the sake of quantity, most people would be thankful to see a real, concise summary of activities and not four pages of nothingness. Also, if you have the chance, think about layout. Categorize your tasks by hierarchy or dependency (which ones need to be done to let the rest happen), mention technologies... if content is not your strength, then focus on shape and strategic organisation of your (limited but real valuable) information.

Comment: Agreed… in addition, talk about why the projects you are working on help the company's overall objectives, using "what and why" language. For instance, "customize infographics that clearly communicate the need for our company's product/service and therefore increase sales".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are for HR to help with annual compensation calculations...

This is a corporate political task more than anything. As such, think like a politician. Make promises that sound good, but can't really be adequately judged upon completion. Promise low, deliver slightly higher. Keep them vague enough where you don't corner yourself. Use as much jargon and corporate buzzwords as you can stomach.

Anything along the lines of 'continuing education' is great. In addition to your professional development classes, I'd throw out things like 'read x number of industry books', 'share industry knowledge with peers', 'expand skill set via online training'. That kind of thing.

Comment: As an in-house graphic designer, I've struggled with this. Unfortunately, you are correct in many ways. Objectives can be a check box for HR. I typically use the opportunity to state what my job duties are and why, and then when we have a self-review, I will go into detail about individual projects.

Comment: Thanks @ispanny5, this has always been so difficult for me, I am not the best BS'er. My manager approved my 4 goals but now needs them drawn out. My whole department is full of editors and I hate looking at there goals because it so lengthy.